# React access Dom Nodes from this.props.children

Tags: reactjs

Let's say I have a Card that contains a login Form

```
 <Card>
     <LoginForm/>
 </Card>
```

How do I access the nodes from the Form within the Card render function?

```
<Form >
  <input type="text" name="email"/>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  <input type="submit"/>
 </Form>
```

Because what i´d like to do is to render the submitbutton not within the props.children context but render it wrapped outside of the given child!

```
render () {
return (
  <div className="card">
      <div className="inner">
        {/* render Children */}
        {this.props.children != undefined ?
          <div className="childrenWrapper">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
          : ""
        }
       </div>
       {/* render submit from login form here, not above  */
  </div>)
```

[image: example expected result]

There are some components which actually do what I want. For example the Tabs component from [react-toolbox](http://react-toolbox.com/#/components/tabs). They somehow manage to render what's within the Tab (children) somewhere else

Just for instance

```
   <Tabs index={this.state.inverseIndex} onChange={this.handleInverseTabChange} inverse>
      <Tab label='First'><small>First Content</small></Tab>
      <Tab label='Second'><small>Second Content</small></Tab>
      <Tab label='Third'><small>Third Content</small></Tab>
      <Tab label='Disabled' disabled><small>Disabled Content</small></Tab>
    </Tabs>
```

Which will lead to the following html 
[image: rendered html example]

As you can see the children from the tab where rendered within their own section
I do not want to change anything on the Form to solve this problem, I would like to pass the Form into the Card and let the Card decide how the Form will be rendered within the card render function.

Since I'm trying to implement the Google Material Design Card [component](https://material.io/guidelines/components/cards.html#cards-actions) and just use it as a template there are more elements coming which will need to be split up and placed at the positions I want them to be. The thing is I could actually place the relevant HTML around the Form to get it as the Card I want it to be, but then I wouldn't need the component at all.

Comment: How about setting a variable with flatButton and then passing it as props to the Card Component? Ah, I forgot: To access the flatButton, I think you could use the ref prop.

Comment: @dschu that works out but the thing is the flatbutton itself is within the form aswell and will then be rendered in the children part aswell

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You would've to pass another prop to the LoginForm component to tell the component to not render the button. In this case you should consider restructuring of your components.

Comment: But what if I dont want to restructure them since I only want to use the card component for different styling. The thing is i cannot just restyle the components since Im in a responsive context. I want to extract the children of the given children to manipulate the html structure to fit my needs

Comment: Why don't you just put an <hr /> inside of the form, then put the submit button after it? As far as I am aware, a Form is just a div that has a "submit" feature inside, so it looks for things with a Name property, and submits those values in a request. Personally, I'd put the card inside the form, instead of the form inside the card

Comment: I know what you mean Jonathan, you want me to put the neccessary HTML in the Form to get what I want, but thats the Question about, finding a way to not handle it like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some decent answers here, but none of them directly answer your question. Therefore, even though you should refactor your code (as elucidated below), I am going to provide you a working solution:

```
class Card extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    console.log(typeof this.props.children)
    return (
      <div>
        {typeof this.props.children === 'object'
          ? React.cloneElement(this.props.children, { ref: (n) => this.form = n })
          : null}
        <button onClick={(e) => console.log(this.form.data)}>submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Form extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {};
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.data = e.target.value;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onChange} />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Card><Form /></Card>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

https://jsbin.com/fohehogozo/edit?js,console,output

By setting a property on the instance, you can then access that property from children by using a `ref`. I checked for `typeof === object` here, because there was only one child.

WARNING: this code is NOT PRODUCTION READY. Do not ever run this in production. The code I have demonstrated is a terrible hack, and you should never try this at home.

---

Comment: Why shouldnt I use this solution since it seems like it is the only way to determine the type of my children ? I mean for sure in this case I can expect the incoming children, because of that I could simply hand them over as properties and use them as stated below. But what if I can´t expect the incoming childrens? Why isnt this a good solution then?

Comment: I had two glasses of wine when I wrote this, a lot of this code can be cleaned up. But having said that, it's _conceptually_ sound, although one can readily see how such code might be difficult to maintain. If you can, it makes sense to refactor to a more idiomatic solution. Escape hatches are called escape hatches for a reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit a form, maybe look at passing down an onChange event and storing the value (based on the name of the field) in the state of the Card. Then attach the onChange event on the inputs so as soon as they're updated, the data will be passed back up to the container for you to submit.

Comment: actually im trying to render a part from the form class on another place in the card class

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you need to do this? It seems to be a code smell

Comment: because i want to render the form normally and if used within a card style it differently. sadly i have to change the html layout aswell and im kinda stuck there

Comment: Override the styles that are breaking it, a lot easier than pulling it out of the component!

Comment: But then I will have to use absolute positioning which is kind of bad in a full responsive website

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to split up the childrens passed, you can simply filter the children array to split up the children, however your childrens seem to be nested.

Why dont you let the cards children handle the separation between your `inner` container and other content?

I think restructuring in this case is more suitable than modifying the passed children property.

Also, pulling the submit button out of the actual form tags, would break your form as it would no longer submit without some custom connection between the button and the actual form.

Answer (score -1):

Don't try to manipulate the DOM; it's generally an anti-pattern in React (though there are a few valid use cases). In your case, rather than literally trying to move the elements, I'd simply hide the button in the form and add it to the parent.

Assuming you have access to the internals of `<LoginForm>`, you can add a prop to hide the button:

```
const button =
  <div class="flatbuttonWrapper">
    <input type="submit"/>
  </div>;

<Form>
  <input type="text" name="email"/>
  <input type="password" name="password"/>
  {!this.props.hideButton && button}
</Form>
```

Add the button to the `Card` component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className="card">
      <div className="inner">
        {this.props.children != undefined ?
          <div className="childrenWrapper">
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
          : ""
        }
      </div>
      <div class="flatbuttonWrapper">
        <input type="submit"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Finally, in your parent:

```
<Card>
  <LoginForm hideButton />
</Card>
```

All that said, it really feels like you need to structure your code better and break some of these components up into smaller, more reusable pieces. For example, the `Card` component probably shouldn't be affecting the button's style or conditionally rendering children; it should just add a frame around any children. Then you can create a more complex component that composes these simpler sub-components to to whatever you need.